# How to set the position update interval with HERE SDK?

Tags: here-api

For a GPS app, I would like to set the interval for the position update, or simply know the frequency which is used. How to do with HERE SDK?

I ask this question because I would like to manage some operations in the  OnPositionChangedListener function. So, that will depend on the interval. Maybe I'll need to use a timer in order to have more control.

In comparison, UWP apps manage that with the properties Geolocator.ReportInterval and Geolocator.DesiredAccuracy.

Comment: It seems that's not possible to set the interval but the interval seems constant. It's about one second when the GPS signal is available, and it's equal to about 20 seconds when the position is got by the network.

I don't know if that's own to the HERE SDK behaviour. I think it is probable that it's own to the Android system.

Answer (score 0):

wait() method can be used to set or specify the time interval at which the density of coordinates need to be captured.

```
public abstract static class NavigationManager.GpsSignalListener
extends java.lang.Object
```

The accuracy of the GPS coordinates depends on many factors, with the result that the computed latitude and longitude can be from 0.5 meters to up to 40 meters away from the actual position. It is often impossible to determine a GPS position inside tunnels, inside buildings or in urban canyons. GPS receivers cannot provide a maximum deviation and thus, for example, are unable to indicate that the calculated location lies within 3.5 meters of the actual location with 95% probability. GPS receivers only provide an HDOP/VDOP/PDOP... value (horizontal/vertical dilution of precision) which indicates that the computed coordinates of a location cannot be more accurate than this value considering the number and/or position of satellites and the mathematical algorithms. This minimum error cannot be used to estimate the maximum error.

GPS heading and speed are computed by the receiver device based on the last several sets of GPS coordinates. The accuracy of the calculation depends on the actual speed of the vehicle and becomes unreliable if the vehicle speed drops below ~10 km/h. At low speeds, even the positional accuracy declines considerably, resulting in large random point clouds in some situations.

Please refer for more details below :

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/index.html